# Why does this function return an lvalue reference given rvalue arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-operator, rvalue-reference, universal-reference

The following definition of a `min` function

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto
min(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(t < u ? t : u)
{
    return t < u ? t : u;
}
```

has a problem: it seems that it's perfectly legal to write

```
min(10, 20) = 0;
```

This has been tested with Clang 3.5 and g++ 4.9.

The solution is straightforward, just use `std::forward` to restore the "rvalue-ness" of the arguments, i.e. modify the body and the `decltype` to say

```
t < u ? std::forward<T>(t) : std::forward<U>(u)
```

However, I'm at a loss to explain **why** the first definition doesn't generate an error.

---

Given my understanding of forwarding and universal references, both `t` and `u` deduce their argument types as `int&&` when passed integer literals. However, within the body of `min`, the arguments have names, so they are lvalues. Now, the [really complicated rules for the conditional operator come into play](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator), but I *think* the pertinent line is:

> - Both E2 [and] E3 are glvalues of the same type. In this case, the result has the same type and value category.

and therefore the return type of `operator?:` should be `int&&` as well, should it not? However, (as far as I can tell) both Clang and g++ have `min(int&&, int&&)` returning an lvalue reference `int&`, thus allowing me to assign to the result.

Clearly there is a gap in my understanding, but I'm not sure exactly what it is that I'm missing. Can anybody explain to me exactly what's going on here?

---

**EDIT:**

As Niall correctly points out, the problem here is not with the conditional operator (which is returning an lvalue of type `int&&` as expected), but with the `decltype`. The rules for `decltype` say

> if the value category of expression is lvalue, then the decltype specifies T&

so the return value of the function becomes `int&& &`, which by the reference collapsing rules of C++11 turns into plain `int&` (contrary to my expected `int&&`).

But if we use `std::forward`, we turn the second and third arguments of `operator?:` (back) into rvalues - specifically, xvalues. Since xvalues are still glvalues (are you keeping up at the back?), the same conditional operator rule applies, and we get a result of the same type and value category: that is, an `int&&` which is an xvalue.

Now, when the function returns, it triggers a different `decltype` rule:

> if the value category of expression is xvalue, then the decltype specifies T&&

This time, the reference collapsing gives us `int&& && = int&&` and, more importantly, the function returns an xvalue. This makes it illegal to assign to the return value, just as we'd like.

Comment: In the body,  I think, you may use std::move to tell the compiler explicitly that you don't need these values any more.

Comment: @Garrappachc As noted, I know the solution (which is to use `std::forward` rather than `std::move`, so the function still works with lvalue args). I'm curious as to why the first (incorrect) definition does what it does.

Comment: The issue may be with the `decltype()` rules if the trailing return type is removed (i.e. `auto min(...) { ... }`) and allow the compiler to deduce it, it returns `int`.

Comment: @Niall I was just editing the question to ask something just like that! Thanks :-)

Comment: The type of the conditional expression isn't an rvalue http://ideone.com/ufbjIQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue may be with the `decltype()` rules.

This is hinted at; if the trailing return type is removed

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto
min(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    return t < u ? t : u;
}
```

and the compiler is allowed to deduce it, the [return type is `int`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4aa73a4e3b27c20).

**Use of decltype**

> `decltype ( expression )`
>   ...
>   if the value category of expression is lvalue, then the decltype specifies T&

Taken from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype).

Since the expression involving `t` and `u` is an lvalue (they are lvalues - named r-value references), the return is the lvalue reference.

In this situation it leads to a potential situation where a literal could be modified. Careful use of forwarding needs to be applied when using ["universal references"](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (or ["forwarding references"](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4164.pdf)) and the associated reference collapsing rules.

As you have already noted, to correct the situation, the correct use of `std::forward` needs to be applied and the return type will be the expected one.

---

For further details on [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) and reference collapsing can be found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3582001/3747990).

Comment: The plain `auto` return case is a bit misleading, because `auto` never deduces a reference (which is why `decltype(auto)` exists in C++14). But the bit about `decltype` forming a reference when given an lvalue argument is exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks :-)

Comment: True, a lot more happens with the `auto`, it was merely the _hint_ to where the issue could be.