# Value category of conditional operator

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, conditional-operator, value-categories

Consider the following code:

```
int x;
int& f() {
  return x ? x : throw 0;
}
```

With `gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)` I get the following compilation error:

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
```

Note that this compiles just fine in clang.  Here is (what I believe to be) the relevant statement from the standard:

> **N4659** [8.16.2.1] (Conditional Operator):
>   The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) throw-expression (8.17); the result is of the type and value category of the other.

As far as I understand, `x` is an lvalue, so it seems to me that `clang` is right.  Am I wrong?

---

If I had to take a guess, the l-to-rvalue conversion is occurring because the two expressions in the conditional don't have the same type, but because the second is a throw this conversion should be preempted.  I'm not familiar with submitting bug reports, but perhaps that would be a better forum for this.

---

Here are some (probably) more helpful questions about the conditional operator:
[Why does this function return an lvalue reference given rvalue arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354868/why-does-this-function-return-an-lvalue-reference-given-rvalue-arguments)
[Error: lvalue required in this simple C code? (Ternary with assignment?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966299/error-lvalue-required-in-this-simple-c-code-ternary-with-assignment)

Comment: It is clearly a bug in g++, the change mentioned by Shafik appears in the standard since C+14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

clang is correct here, the old behavior was to unconditionally convert the value to a *prvalue* which it looks like gcc still implements.

This was the subject of [DR 1560](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1560) which was fixed by the resolution of [DR 1550](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1550). DR 1560 says:

> A glvalue appearing as one operand of a conditional-expression in
>   which the other operand is a throw-expression is converted to a
>   prvalue, regardless of how the conditional-expression is used:
>
> > If either the second or the third operand has type void, then the lvalue-to-rvalue (7.1 [conv.lval]), array-to-pointer (7.2
> >     [conv.array]), and function-to-pointer (7.3 [conv.func]) standard
> >     conversions are performed on the second and third operands, and one of
> >     the following shall hold:
> >
> > - The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression (18.1 [except.throw]); the result is of the type of
> >       the other and is a prvalue.
>
> This seems to be gratuitous and surprising.

and `DR 1550` changed the wording in [[expr.cond]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#2.1) to what we have now:

> The second or the third operand (but not both) is a (possibly parenthesized) throw-expression; the result is of the type and value category of the other. The conditional-expression is a bit-field if that operand is a bit-field.

So it looks like gcc is implementing the old behavior while clang is implementing the DR.

This is the [patch that applied DR 1560 to clang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/commit/908319e459c087ad06abb9d36366fe33f9fe47f9). It added the following test:

```
namespace DR1560 { // dr1560: 3.5
  void f(bool b, int n) {
    (b ? throw 0 : n) = (b ? n : throw 0) = 0;
  }
  class X { X(const X&); };
  const X &get();
  const X &x = true ? get() : throw 0;
}
```

which [on godbolt we can see this fails for gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/14Lsd-) due to:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
4 |     (b ? throw 0 : n) = (b ? n : throw 0) = 0;
  |
```

We have a gcc [bug report for a very similar issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64372) which has the following reduced test case:

> I wanted to bump this bug and supply a simpler test-case:
>
> ```
> void blah(int&) {}
>
> int main() {
>     int i{};
>     blah(true ? i : throw);
> }
> ```
>
> result with gcc 6.0:
>
> ```
> prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cc:6:15: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from an rvalue of type 'int'
>      blah(true ? i : throw 0);
>           ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```