# Ternary operator with xvalue operands

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, value-categories

Say we have a ternary operator with 2 xvalue operands.

```
struct A {
    A() { std::cout<<"A ctor"<<std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout<<"A dtor"<<std::endl; }
    A(A const&) { std::cout<<"A copy ctor"<<std::endl; }
    A(A&&) { std::cout<<"A move ctor"<<std::endl; }

    void foo() & { std::cout<<"A&.foo()"<<std::endl; }
    void foo() const& { std::cout<<"A const&.foo()"<<std::endl; }
    void foo() && { std::cout<<"A&&.foo()"<<std::endl; }
    void foo() const&& { std::cout<<"A const&&.foo()"<<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A a2;
    (true? static_cast<A&&>(a) : static_cast<A&&>(a2)).foo();
    return 0;
}
```

According to cppreference conditional operator

> 4) If E2 and E3 are glvalues of the same type and the same value
>   category, then the result has the same type and value category, and is
>   a bit-field if at least one of E2 and E3 is a bit-field.

The result should be also A&& and no copy or move constructors are expected. Am I correct?

But gcc, clang and Visual Studio give different results on this.

gcc: `A&.foo()`

clang: `A&&.foo()`

VS:

```
A move ctor
A&&.foo()
```

If we cast both operand types to `A const&&`, gcc will be `A const&.foo()`, clang will be `A const&&.foo()`, VS will be `A const&&.foo()` with a copy ctor called.

Is clang the correct one on this? Thanks!

Comment: The result is an xvalue of type `A`; the output should be the same as `std::move(a).foo();`

Comment: It should be `A&&.foo()` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130847/1505939)

Comment: Yes clang is correct. MSVC is wrong to make a copy. I posted a bug report for gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88103

Comment: Somewhat related [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53328407/1708801) where gcc also gets it incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct output of the program execution is:

```
A ctor
A ctor
A&&.foo()
A dtor
A dtor
```

The corresponding GCC bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88103 was fixed in GCC 7.5, 8.3, 9.1 versions. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6hbaW4W5q

The latest MSVC also prints correct output.